# Using data from excel in PHP function

Tags: php, excel

I have written some PHP that uses a simple HTML form to take in an ISBN number, uses that number to search Amazon's database, gets the book title and pricing information and then exports the information to notepad.

What I need to do now is change it so that a large number of ISBN's can be searched automatically.  I was thinking I could do it either by having an excel sheet of ISBN's that I upload, or copy and pasting all of the ISBN's at once into a form.

I need some guidance on how to do this.  I do not have a lot of PHP experience.

Thanks!

Comment: You're fishing for opinions. There is no "best way". There's ways that work, and ways that don't. How can it be done? writing code is a good start.

Comment: I am asking for guidance or help on how to write that code...I do not have a lot of PHP experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a PHP library I use for my Excel needs: [PHPExcel](https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/)

It comes with good [examples](https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples&referringTitle=Home) and [documentation](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/wiki/User%20Documentation) to get you started.